# Line used for handling errors always called

Tags: excel, vba

### Some Context Into The Project (Skip this if you don't care)

Recently, I have been tasked to build a solution that allows my teammates and I to quickly deal with what we call "Recipes". The unfortunate thing is that any other language like Python cannot be used because all the files are encrypted unless they are opened in specific programs. Excel is one of them and because of this our entire office is inclined to use VBA for everything. Coming from literally every language I've ever worked in, VBA is... Horrible to develop complex projects in (just an opinion), so I've ventured to make my (and my co-worker's) life easier by starting a library of various Types, Functions, Classes, etc.

### The Problem

For some reason, the following code will always execute the `alreadyExists` `Line` instead of only executing when the `Error` is raised:

```
Private Sub SetName(index As Integer, name As String)
    On Error GoTo alreadyExists

    If (Not NameExists(name)) Then
        internalName(index) = name
    Else
        Err.Raise 515, "SetName", "Name exists"
    End If

alreadyExists:
    MsgBox ("Name already exists in array.")
    End
End Sub
```

Other `Subs` handle this pattern just fine, but this one `Sub` keeps running the `alreadyExists` error. The `Sub` that calls this would be:

```
Public Sub Insert(data As Variant, Optional name As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    If (Not internalData) = -1 Then
        i = 0
    Else
        i = UBound(internalData) + 1
    End If
    Call ResizeTo(i)

    If name = "" Then
        internalName(i) = i
    Else
        SetName i, name
    End If

    internalData(i) = data
End Sub
```

If you feel like all the code is necessary then you can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/Hqb2DEWj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have that kind of error, you have to put an `Exit Sub` before the error handler otherwise it's going to be read like any other part of the code.

```
Private Sub SetName(index As Integer, name As String)
    On Error GoTo alreadyExists

    If (Not NameExists(name)) Then
        internalName(index) = name
    Else
        Err.Raise 515, "SetName", "Name exists"
    End If

Exit Sub 

alreadyExists:
    MsgBox ("Name already exists in array.")
    End
End Sub
```

Comment: *sigh* There are certain times where I regret the questions that I asked for the answers simplicity is obvious. This is one of those times. Thank you.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `End` - the next line is `End Sub`

Comment: The `End` is actually there to completely stop the program, or at least I think that's what it does. I haven't gone through and actually tested it. If it does do what I think it does, I have it there as a way of shunning off proper error handling, heh.